# Why would a loop die?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using a simple loop to restart a process if it dies.  Occasionally I've seen the loop stop, which of course it shouldn't do. What could be some causes of this? I'm using a low end node/vps running ubuntu 14.  Thanks. :)

This is the loop I use.

```
 #!/bin/bash/
 period=${1:-60}
while :
do
sleep 20 &
sh restart.sh
wait
done
```

This is restart.sh.. it greps the current PID of 'ffmpeg' and if its not found, it re-runs the ffmpeg command which broadcasts my own internet radio station, which I can then listen to anywhere :)

```
 #!/bin/bash/
pgrep ffmpeg
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then killall ffmpeg
killall rtmpdump
sleep 1
nohup ffmpeg (a bunch of ffmpeg stuff) &
fi
```

So your saying this could be an issue with ffmpeg hanging/freezing, rather then the loop dieing out?  Is there ways I could improve what I am doing here? TBH I'm only about a month into linux and a week into bash, so this is the best I could do.

Thanks for your help so far, it was very useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what `restart.sh` does, it appears the script could `wait` forever if `sh restart.sh` hangs. By specifying `wait` with no `PID`, it will **wait until all process IDs known to the invoking shell have terminated** (see `man 1P wait`). If `sh restart.sh` hangs, `wait` is never satisfied.

If there is no specific requirement to background sleep, why not run sleep in the foreground and omit `wait` altogether:

```
#!/bin/bash/
period=${1:-60}
while :
do
  sleep 20
  sh restart.sh
done
```

Comment: Your explaination makes a lot of sense!! I appreciate it. I added more information to the main post in case it helps.  Regardless if you revisit this post, I will mark as correct anwser later.   Thanks!! :)